# iOS: When a scrollview is loaded are all the subviews of the scrollview loaded or is it just the ones visible at any one moment?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

If the content view of the scrollview is bigger than the scrollview, will the scrollview load every subview of the content view when it is initially loaded or will it just load what is seen and load the rest when the scrollview scrolls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `UIScrollView` will load all its subviews into memory. If you want a scroll view to only load the "subviews" that are visible, I'd recommend using a `UITableView`, `UICollectionView`, or `UIStackView`.